# Dell Vostro 3750 finger print scanner

Tags: drivers, dell-vostro, fingerprint-reader

I have a Dell 3750 that runs Ubuntu 14.4Lts. I also have a finger print scanner that does not seem to work with Ubuntu with my current set up. The finger print scanner comes up as VFS5011 Fingerprint Reader.

Are there any drivers or compatibility layers that I can download so that it is compatible?